# Unable to find result when searching for "&" literal in solr index

Tags: indexing, solr, escaping, full-text-search, solr5

I am using solr 5 and trying to search for H&R in my index which has H&R block as a value for one of the field, tried various ways by escaping & with /& when searching but I am unable to find any results for it. could someone please help if I need to include any special tokenizers for it to return results?
I am using following filters for querying
 `<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/> <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/> <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/> <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>`

I tried for searching H/&R, but it didn't work

Comment: The escape character is a backslash - \ - not `/`. You'll also want to look at the analysis page to make sure that `&` is kept as part of the token through the whole chain.

Comment: @MatsLindh I looked at the analysis page already, there is & through the whole filter chain on both the index side and query side as well, sorry for the escaping thing, I will try with the / as well. Backslash didn't work 
Thanks for responding

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot of my analyzer here https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/usk8ip4nrzhfhjybkwf0i/Screenshot-2024-02-20-at-1.58.35-PM.png?rlkey=ohhmkgxag7jo8bvcrflqt970r&dl=0

Comment: Your analysis chain seems correct (but please use SO's image hosting so that the image don't disappear in the future for anyone else coming across this thread). It'd probably be helpful if you include the actual query string you're sending to Solr as well, and how the query looks if you make it from Solr's admin page.

Comment: This is the url, I am trying /solr/test_core/select?q=*%3A*&fq=name%3AH\&R&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: If you append `debug=all` to your query string you'll see exactly how the query string gets parsed as well, it might be helpful to find out what's happening. I'd also try wrapping it between quotes (`"`).